# SQL Server xp_cmdshell query: add variables to command

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I have the query working correctly, but I want to be able to add a date value variable within the command.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @varDate DATE

SET @varDate = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -E -S "EMERALDSERVER\LASERFICHERIO" -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON EXEC PullSageData.[dbo].[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > C:\Laserfiche\import\Reports\Reports_"+@varDate+".csv'
```

Where the `@varDate` is located should just replace with yesterdays date.

Example file name:

```
Reports_2018_10_31.csv
```

instead it outputs the filename:

```
Reports+@varDate+.csv
```

My guess is that entering a variable within single quotes isn't applied with double quotes and + like I have been seeing in so many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new variable that contains everything and execute from it
Example:

```
declare @varDate date
SET @varDate=CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) as date)
declare @Script varchar (max) = 'SQLCMD -E -S "EMERALDSERVER\LASERFICHERIO" -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON EXEC PullSageData.[dbo].[Report_Daily_Superintendent_Jobs]" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > C:\Laserfiche\import\Reports\Reports_varDate.csv'
declare @cmd varchar(max)= replace(@Script,'@varDate',@varDate)
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: The only thing I modified was xp_cmdshell cannot use varchar(max),  I just replaced with a large string size varchar(1000).  Thanks!

Comment: This will work, but you'll receive an error stating `Could not find stored procedure master..xp_cmdshell @cmd` To fix it, change the above execution to: `EXEC (master..xp_cmdshell @cmd)`